# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

estoy tratando de hacer una Web, y quiero implementarle un sistema de inicio de sesion, pero al darle registrar en el formulario, me salta el siguiente error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on
>   bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\funciones.php:15 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\register\register.php(6): registro() #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\funciones.php on line 15

Este es el codigo

```
 function registro() {
    require_once('conexiones.php');
    $errores = [];

    $nombre = limpiar($_POST['nombre']);
    $apellido = limpiar($_POST['apellido']);
    $user = limpiar($_POST['user']);
    $contraseña = limpiar($_POST['contraseña']);
    $correo = limpiar($_POST['correo']);
    $pais = limpiar($_POST['pais']);

    $dec = $con -> prepare("INSERT INTO `perfiles` ('nombre', 'apellido', 'user', 'contraseña', 'correo', 'pais') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $dec -> bind_param("ssssss", $nombre, $apellido, $user, $contraseña, $correo, $pais);
    $dec -> execute();
    $resultado = $dec -> affected_rows;
    $dec -> free_result();
    $dec -> close();
    $con -> close();

    if ($resultado == 1) {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $user;
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else {
        $errores[] = 'Problemas tecnicos en estos momentos';
    }

    return $errores;

}

function limpiar($datos) {
    $datos = trim($datos);
    $datos = stripcslashes($datos);
    $datos = htmlspecialchars($datos);
    return $datos;
}
```

Comment: Primer observación: no dejes esos espacios en blanco en cada uno de los renglones, es decir `-> algo` quita ese espacio entre la flechiat y los métodos

Comment: Vale gracias por el consejo, soy nuevo utilizando php y mysql, pero aun no logro saber el porque el error, ya recibe en el db el nombre de las columnas y todo encaja, pero no se si sea por alguna comilla o escribi algo mal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en la query, para el nombre de las columnas se utiliza ` (tilde abierta) en lugar de ' (comilla).

Por ende, al dar error al preparar la query, lo anterior es false en lugar de un resultado, por ende, un bool, al cual no se le puede bindear nada.

Si eres nuevo en PHP, no te compliques la vida, entiendo que $con es el link de mysqli, sería tan fácil como:

```
 $con->query('INSERT INTO `perfiles` (`nombre`, `apellido`, `user`, `contraseña`, `correo`, `pais`) VALUES (\'' . $nombre . '\', \'' . $apellido. '\', \'' . $user . '\', \'' . $contraseña. '\', \'' . $correo. '\', \'' . $pais . '\')');
```

No obstante, si lo quieres hacer como lo haces, esto debería solucionar el problema de tu prepared statement:

```
$dec = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `perfiles` (`nombre`, `apellido`, `user`, `contraseña`, `correo`, `pais`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Indicar además, que para evitar inyecciones SQL, y limpiar los datos con ello (aunque nombre, apellidos, etc. debe llevar una limpieza más específica, al igual que comprobar que el email y país sean válidos), deberías utilizar **mysqli_real_escape_string**.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, intente tal cual me comentaste pero aun asi persiste el error, este es el codigo que utilizo para conectarme a la base de datos 

<?php 
 $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "usuarios");
 if ($con->connect_error) {
  die('Conexión no establecida: ' . $con->connect_error);
 }

?>

Comment: @LuisArturoRamosRomero edito la pregunta, te pongo el código exacto para la query, prueba así. Si no funciona, debería ver el código entero...

Comment: Vale, cuando me comentaste sobre las comillas, se las cambie en el codigo para acceder a la base de datos y ya no me da el error, pero ahora me salta esto ''Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)'' no tengo password para acceder a phpmyadmin y desconozco esto

Comment: @LuisArturoRamosRomero si mal no recuerdo, por seguridad se bloqueaban las conexiones a root sin contraseña a la base de datos. Ponle una, es fácil, ejecuta esta consulta en phpMyAdmin: SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('aquí tu contraseña');

Comment: @LuisArturoRamosRomero si no tienes contraseña asignada a tu gestor, entonces en tu método de conexión de mysqli solo basta con que dejes unas comillas vacías así: `""` indicando que no existe valor para ese parámetro

Comment: @LuisArturoRamosRomero eso es correcto, pero constantemente actualizan MySQL e implementan nuevas características de seguridad, por ejemplo el reciente nuevo cifrado de contraseñas, que daba problemas con el api de MySQLi de PHP, entre otros. Además, siempre debería tener una contraseña...

Comment: Vale, le ingrese una password mediante el config.inc.php y edite los privilegios del root@localhost colocandole la misma password, la ingrese en el codigo para ingresar a la db, pero me sigo dando el mismo error... es algo que estoy haciendo mal, pero no lo consigo

Comment: @LuisArturoRamosRomero ¿lo has cambiado por el código de la parte superior? Si no, repito, por favor, pon el código entero con los cambios realizados e indica de nuevo el error, no sé si te refieres al de la conexión o al de preparar el statement

Comment: Disculpa, este es el error completo ''Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\terrorcity\conexiones.php on line 2
Conexión no establecida: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)'' es cuando intento acceder a la db mediante la funcion de registro de usuario, le coloque una password por el config.ini.php y le estableci una en phpmyadmin, y tiene todos los privilegios, no se que otra cosa pueda ser

Comment: @LuisArturoRamosRomero no sé a que te refieres con el config.inc.php, si te refieres a algo específico de phpMyAdmin, no tiene nada que ver. La contraseña hay que ponérsela al usuario del DBMS (MySQL), en este caso root, tal y como te indiqué arriba. Una vez la tengas, donde debes poner la contraseña es en tu conexión $algo = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'contraseña', 'db');

Comment: Vale ya vi donde ejecutar la consulta, deja pruebo y te digo